# Aggregate data in sql to one line

Tags: sql

I have this table

```
person_id   Pay_seq Pay_cd      Pay1_Amt    Pay2_Amt    Pay3_Amt    Pay4_Amt
1234          1     2341       -38257.68    NULL        NULL        NULL
1234          2     3421        NULL        0.00        NULL        NULL
1234          3     4321        NULL        NULL        0.00        NULL
1234          4     4321        Null        NULL        NULL        NULL
```

and want to have a table like this

```
person_id   Pay_cd1  Pay1_Amt    Pay_cd2    Pay2_Amt Pay_cd3    Pay3_Amt Pay_cd4    Pay4_Amt
1234        2341    -$38,257.68  3421       $0.00    4321       $0.00    4321       $0.00
```

How do i do this in sql?

Comment: So, whats you question? Do you need to change NULL's for 0's?

Comment: ..Are you looking for `GROUP BY`?

Comment: pay_seq correlates to pay_amt and the Pay codes. i.e. Pay1_Amt correlates to Pay_seq 1.  Pay_cd 2341 correlates to pay_seq 1. I want to rename Pay_cd  where the pay_seq = 1 to Pay_cd1 and aggregate the data to one line. I have many person_ids in my the larger table I am working with

Comment: Why would you structure your table like that, why not have an item, and a cost? It seems weird to have items, and three columns that are unused.

Comment: Don't get it. Please explain the logic of what you're looking for...

Comment: I have many people in a table and want each to have one line of data.

Comment: That's not how you generally structure a table. You would have one table for persons, one for items, and one "person_items" that maps a person to an item. If you do that, then your queries would be *much* easier to construct.

Comment: lets see if i can make this simpler. I want pay_cd to be renamed Pay_cd1 when the pay_seq = 1 and so on. then I would like to have the data aggregated to one line.

Comment: I just re-read your first answer... substuting the nulls for zeros will work, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not normalized and makes querying for data difficult.  Anyway, I do believe you are after ([**SQL Fiddle)**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6617f/9/0):

```
SELECT person_id, 
  t1.Pay_cd AS Pay_cd1, t1.Pay1_Amt, 
  t2.Pay_cd AS Pay_cd2, t2.Pay2_Amt,
  t3.Pay_cd AS Pay_cd3, t3.Pay3_Amt,
  t4.Pay_cd AS Pay_cd4, t4.Pay4_Amt
FROM MyTable t1
  LEFT JOIN MyTable t2 ON t1.person_id = t2.person_id and t2.Pay_seq = 2
  LEFT JOIN MyTable t3 ON t1.person_id = t3.person_id and t3.Pay_seq = 3
  LEFT JOIN MyTable t4 ON t1.person_id = t4.person_id and t4.Pay_seq = 4
WHERE t1.Pay_seq = 1
```

If you have a value that is `null` and want it to return `0.00` instead then you can do something like:

```
CASE WHEN t4.Pay4_Amt IS NULL THEN 0.00 ELSE t4.Pay4_Amt END AS Pay4_Amt
```

So the full query would look like ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f6617f/8/0)):

```
SELECT t1.person_id, 
  t1.Pay_cd AS Pay_cd1, t1.Pay1_Amt, 
  t2.Pay_cd AS Pay_cd2, CASE WHEN t2.Pay2_Amt IS NULL THEN 0.00 ELSE t2.Pay2_Amt END AS Pay2_Amt,
  t3.Pay_cd AS Pay_cd3, CASE WHEN t3.Pay3_Amt IS NULL THEN 0.00 ELSE t3.Pay3_Amt END AS Pay3_Amt,
  t4.Pay_cd AS Pay_cd4, CASE WHEN t4.Pay4_Amt IS NULL THEN 0.00 ELSE t4.Pay4_Amt END AS Pay4_Amt
FROM MyTable t1
  LEFT JOIN MyTable t2 ON t1.person_id = t2.person_id and t2.Pay_seq = 2
  LEFT JOIN MyTable t3 ON t1.person_id = t3.person_id and t3.Pay_seq = 3
  LEFT JOIN MyTable t4 ON t1.person_id = t4.person_id and t4.Pay_seq = 4
WHERE t1.Pay_seq = 1
```

Comment: Clever, but might need LEFT joins if each person does not have all 4 related records.

Comment: **@D Stanley**, Agreed, I updated my answer to reflect suggestion.

Comment: needed left joins just in case anyone was curious